# Python nested generator function: Outer function not reflecting change in object

Tags: python, python-2.7, generator

I have a generator function (newfunc), which yields an object (of class X) from another generator function (func), in the following way:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

class X(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.state = 'oldstate'

    def set_state(self, state):
        self.state = state

    def get_state(self):
        return self.state

xobj1 = X()
xobj2 = X()

@contextmanager
def func(xobj, someVar):
    print someVar
    yield xobj

@contextmanager
def newfunc():
    with func(xobj1, 1) as x1:
        with func(xobj2, 2) as x2:
            yield x2
            x1 = x2 %setting to potentially changed object.

with newfunc() as x:
    x.set_state('newstate')
```

Now, since x1 is being set to x2, I would expect xobj1's state to also reflect 'newstate'. However, only xobj2's state is set to 'newstate'. Shouldn't both objects have been changed? Specifically, what should be done to ensure that both change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assignment operations on custom objects does not copy or overwrite them. `x1` and `x2` are variables containing references to their respective objects. When you write:

```
x1 = x2
```

You are saying: "x1 should refer to the same object as x2". You are in no way altering the object initially referred to by `x1`. If you want only the `state` attribute to be copied from one object to the other, you need to do:

```
x1.set_state(x2.get_state())
```

Which calls `set_state` on the object referenced by x1 (xobj1).

And so forth, for every attribute that needs to be transferred. To make it cleaner, you can create a new method in class X:

```
def copy_state(self, other):
    self.set_state(other.get_state())
    self.set_x(other.get_x())
    ...
```

Also to make getters and setters cleaner, you should look into *properties* which is the "clean" way in python to make encapsulated attributes.